# Matching a url that contains upper case characters and no file extensions

Tags: c#, regex, iis

Looking for help as described in the title - I need to ONLY match urls that have upper cases characters somewhere within the string AND do NOT have a file extension, which I wish to specify within the expression itself.

Have had no problem matching the upper case segments but I don't seem to be able to find a way to find the ones that don't have extensions on them.

I.e. this should not hit:

```
http://www.example.com/upload/campaigns/TOY/img/test-logo.svg
```

This should not hit

```
http://www.example.com/upload/campaigns/toy/testpage
```

But this should

```
http://www.example.com/upload/campaigns/TOY/testpage
```

I have this atm, which currently only selects periods, but I think it's somewhat close to what I actually need.

```
([A-Z\-_0-9\/\:\.]*\.(?!jpg|jpeg|png|gif))
```

**Edit: I now have this:**

```
([A-Z\-_0-9\/\:\.]*\.(?!.*(?:svg|jpe?g|png|gif)$).*)
```

I'm testing on http://regexr.com/ and enabling `/m` gives me the desired results, so I need to include this as part of my expression or is it just applicable in this testing scenario? In production, the expression will be used as a single string in part of a url re-write.

Comment: Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow -- we expect questions here to relate to *specific* programming problems -- but we will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us [what you've tried](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and where you are stuck. This will also help us answer your question better.

Comment: There is no difference between the two links too.

Comment: Sorry, I'd been trying some other stuff and didn't think what I had at that point was a useful starting point to post, luckily I still had a more recent one in my clipboard.

Comment: Do you need to disallow specific extensions only or any dot in the last subpart? Try [`^((?!.*\.(?:svg|jpe?g|png|gif)$).*)$`](https://regex101.com/r/VMFe7g/1)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Specific extensions. I tried you idea but it doen't seem to differentiate between them when combined with the first part. Edit, I'm using regexr, should i have /g or /m on?

Comment: Your question is totally unclear. Please clarify what you have, what you need to get. Only your title seems to have some coherent information. Maybe you need `^(?!.*\.(?:svg|jpe?g|png|gif)$)(?=.*[A-Z]).*$`. Or instead of `(?=.*[A-Z])`, you need `(?=.*\/[A-Z]+\/)`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Sorry, I've edited it. Does it make more sense now?

Comment: You may use `([\w/:.-]*\.(?!.*(?:svg|jpe?g|png|gif)$).*)` in your prod. environment. `/m` is only needed at the demo site where you test a multiline string.

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew, that works great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
([\w/:.-]*\.(?!.*(?:svg|jpe?g|png|gif)$).*)
```

in your production environment. `/m` modifier is only needed at the demo site where you test a multiline string.

**Details**:

- `(`  - Capturing group 1 matching:

  - [\w/:.-]*`- zero or more more word chars (letters, digits or`_`),`/`,`:`,`.`and`-` symbols
  - `\.` - a dot
  - `(?!.*(?:svg|jpe?g|png|gif)$).*` - any 0+ chars up to the end (`.*`) if there is no `svg`, `jpg`, `jpeg`, `png` or `gif` at the end of the string
- `)` - end of Group 1.